# If AH and BG are angle bisectors, how would I find IJ?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Nln.png)

I've tried finding it, but it just doesn't seem to come out.

I found $$GC=\dfrac{4}{3}$$ $$AG=\dfrac{5}{3}$$ and $$GB=\dfrac{4\sqrt{10}}{3}$$ I really don't know what to do from here, could someone help me?

Comment: Do you know trigonometry?

Comment: No, I haven't gotten to it yet. I'm wondering if this is solvable without trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

Let $IJ=r$, $IK$ be a perpendicular from $I$ to $AC$ and $IL$ be a perpendicular from $I$ to $AB.$

Thus, since $IJCK$ is square, we obtain
$$AL+BL=AB$$ or
$$3-r+4-r=5,$$ which gives $$r=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Point $I$ is the [incenter](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordincenter.html) of $\Delta ABC$. Let $B = (0,0)$, $C = (4,0)$ and $A = (4,3)$. Then, the y-coordinate of $I$ is:

$$\frac{3\cdot0+4\cdot3 + 5\cdot0}{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

Knowing $AG$, you can figure out $BI : IG$ by the angle bisector theorem. Then use $\triangle BIJ \sim \triangle BGC$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know area of a triangle is also:
$\Delta=rs$
Where $r$ is inradius and $s$ is semiperimeter.
$\Delta$ = 1/2 × base × height 
Form the equation and you will get $IJ$.
$IJ$ = 1
(If you need to cross check)